# Como repetir un bloque de try and catch

Tags: java, bucles, try-catch

tengo una duda sobre como repetir cuantas veces se nesecita un codigo, hasta que el usuario agregue por completo los datos que son correctos. Les presento mi codigo para que sea mas entendible.

```
        boolean proceder_bloque1 = false;
    do{
        try{
            int cant_iniciales = scan.nextInt();
            int contador_programas_iniciales = 0; //para saber cuantos programas se han ingresado, servira tambien pera ir evaluando el bucle
            int posicion_programa_inicial = 0;//sirve para las posiciones en que se agregan los objetos, va aumentando en cada iteracion
            Memoria programas_iniciales[] = new Memoria[cant_iniciales];//arreglo de tipo memoria que tiene como longitud la cantidad de programas iniciales    
            //se creara un bucle hasta que se cumpla la cantidad de programas iniciales a ejecutar
            do{
                //Usuario ingresa nombre
                System.out.println("Sin espacios por favor escriba el nombre del programa");
                String nombre_programa_inicial = scan.next();
                memoria.setNombrePrograma(nombre_programa_inicial);
                //Usuario ingresa el tiempo de ejecucion
                System.out.println("Ingrese tiempo de ejecucion que tendra el programa");
                int tiempo_ejecucion_programa_inicial = scan.nextInt();
                memoria.setTiempoEjecucion(tiempo_ejecucion_programa_inicial);
                //El usuario ingresara memoria que ocupa el programa inicial
                System.out.println("Ingrese memoria que ocupa el programa que desea ejecutar");
                int memoria_programa_inicial = scan.nextInt();
                memoria.setEspacio(memoria_programa_inicial);

                //se crea el arreglo de objeto memoria y se guarda la informacion dada por el usuario
                programas_iniciales[posicion_programa_inicial] = new Memoria(memoria.getNombrePrograma(),memoria.getEspacio(),memoria.getTiempoEjecucion());
                
                //en cada bucle se aumenta la posicion y el contador, para que el bucle no sea infinito y la posicion donde se agreguen los datos, no sean los mismos
                posicion_programa_inicial ++;
                contador_programas_iniciales ++;
            
            }while(contador_programas_iniciales < cant_iniciales);
            proceder_bloque1 = true;

        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("No ha ingresado un dato valido, por favor vuelva a intentar, por favor revise y vuelva a intentar");
        }
    }while(proceder_bloque1 == false);
```

Lo que quiero hacer es de que haya una condicion de verificacion. Luego de eso que el programa verifique que el usuario este ingresando todos los datos correspondientes. Si el usuario agrega la informacion correspondiente con los datos correspondientes, entonces el programa sigue como si nada.

Pero si el usuario por ejemplo agrega una "p" donde debe ir un valor, quiero que el codigo que esta en try se repita hasta que el usuario deje de agregar letras donde van numeros y asi...pero no estoy seguro de como hacer el bucle, lo que he hecho hasta ahora solo me imprime infinitas veces que el dato no es valido. Cosa que nesecito solo una vez y que luego vuelva a intentar el codigo...me podrian ayudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero te menciono los errores encontrados en tu código

> boolean proceder_bloque1 = false;

No veo el sentido de esta variable proceder_bloque1

> while(proceder_bloque1 == false)

Cuando evalúas un booleano no se compara se esa manera, la forma correcta sería

```
while(!proceder_bloque1)
```

> String nombre_programa_inicial = scan.next();

Las variables locales que usas decláralo fuera del bucle para que no tengas que reservar memoria en cada iteración.

> programas_iniciales[posicion_programa_inicial] = new Memoria(memoria.getNombrePrograma(),memoria.getEspacio(),memoria.getTiempoEjecucion());

En cada bucle estas instanciando un arreglo de objetos, sólo se instancia 1 vez y fuera del bucle, otro error es que en cada lectura de datos estas seteando los valores y cuando instancias un nuevo objeto inicializas en su constructor; lo que debes hacer es usar el constructor o usar los Setter de tu clase Memoria.

> int contador_programas_iniciales = 0; //para saber cuantos programas se han ingresado, servira tambien pera ir evaluando el bucle
> int posicion_programa_inicial = 0;//sirve para las posiciones en que se agregan los objetos, va aumentando en cada iteracion

No es necesario crear 2 contadores, `contador_programas_iniciales` puedes usar para saber cuantos programas se ha ingresado y para agregar los objetos en la posición que corresponde.

**Te dejo el código funcional**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);        
    
            int cant_iniciales = scan.nextInt();
            int contador_programas_iniciales = 0; //para saber cuantos programas se han ingresado, servira tambien pera ir evaluando el bucle           
            Memoria programas_iniciales[] = new Memoria[cant_iniciales];//arreglo de tipo memoria que tiene como longitud la cantidad de programas iniciales  
            String nombre_programa_inicial;
            String tiempo_ejecucion_programa_inicial;
            String memoria_programa_inicial;
            boolean numeric;
            Memoria memoria;
            
            //se creara un bucle hasta que se cumpla la cantidad de programas iniciales a ejecutar
            do{
                
                //Usuario ingresa nombre
                System.out.println("Sin espacios por favor escriba el nombre del programa");
                nombre_programa_inicial = scan.next();
                
                numeric=false;
                do{
                    //Usuario ingresa el tiempo de ejecucion
                    System.out.println("Ingrese tiempo de ejecucion que tendra el programa");
                    tiempo_ejecucion_programa_inicial = scan.next();
                    //validamos si el valor ingresado es numérico
                    if(isNumeric(tiempo_ejecucion_programa_inicial)){
                        numeric=true;//si es valor numerico cambiamos el valor de numeric a true para leer el siguiente dato
                    }
                    else System.out.println("No ha ingresado un dato valido, por favor revise y vuelva a intentar");
                }while(!numeric);
                
                numeric=false;
                do{
                    //El usuario ingresara memoria que ocupa el programa inicial
                    System.out.println("Ingrese memoria que ocupa el programa que desea ejecutar");
                    memoria_programa_inicial = scan.next();
                    if(isNumeric(nombre_programa_inicial)){
                        numeric=true;
                    }
                    else System.out.println("No ha ingresado un dato valido, por favor revise y vuelva a intentar");
                }while(!numeric);
                    
                //se crea el arreglo de objeto memoria y se guarda la informacion dada por el usuario 
                memoria= new Memoria();
                memoria.setNombrePrograma(nombre_programa_inicial);
                memoria.setTiempoEjecucion(tiempo_ejecucion_programa_inicial);
                memoria.setEspacio(memoria_programa_inicial);   
                //agregamos 1 objeto de tipo Memoria al arreglo de Memoria
                programas_iniciales[contador_programas_iniciales]= memoria;                
                contador_programas_iniciales ++;//aumentamos el contador para almacenar en el siguiente posicion del arreglo
            
            }while(contador_programas_iniciales < cant_iniciales);           
       
    }
    
    private static boolean isNumeric(String cadena){
       try {
           Integer.parseInt(cadena);
           return true;
       } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
           return false;
       }
    }
```

**Explicación del código**
El código está comentado pero igual me gustaría recalcar algunos puntos

1. Todas las variables están declarados fuera del bucle.
2. No abuses del Try Catch, esto es usado para el manejo de errores que se escapan de las manos, si puedes tratar los posibles errores sin el Try Catch hazlo.
3. Lo que hice con las variables de tipo entero es cambiarlo a tipo String, esto con la finalidad de evaluar en un método aparte si se trata de valor entero o no.
4. En cada lectura de los valores de tipo entero se llama al método `isNumeric` en caso si el valor ingresado no es entero volverá a pedir que ingrese los datos.
5. Al evaluar el ingreso de todos los datos recién Seteamos en el objeto de tipo Memoria y por último agregamos cada objeto leido en nuestro arreglo de tipo Memoria.